# Google Chrome extension that can maintain a list of blacklisted URLs

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can maintain a list of blacklisted URLs so that no new tab pointing to that URL can be created. It should make it easy to add URLs to the blacklist, e.g. if the user visit an URL, there should be some button or context menu option to blacklist it.

Comment: Should it also block content from that website, for instance blocking a video from blockedsite.com embedded inside a oksite.com web page?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ideally yes, but it is fine if it doesn't do it.

Comment: I wonder how AdBlock behaves when you try to open a new tab to a blocked website.

Comment: How is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-blocker/jpakadanffilpnjijlmmkljogkfaognd/related?hl=en?